# Seeding Date objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a seed file and i need to fill some :date fields but i get **ArgumentError: invalid date** when i run rake db:seed here's an extract of my seed code:

```
d1 = DateTime.new(2015,22,06)
d2 = DateTime.new(2015,11,06)
d3 = DateTime.new(2015,28,06)

Event.create!([{
    name: "Test Event NC",
    start_on: d1,
    finish_on: d1,
    certificate: false,
    free: true, 
    ven: false,
    capacity: 100,
    address: "3250 1st Ave 350",
    client: px
    }])
```

and my db schema

```
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.date     "start_on"
t.date     "finish_on"
t.boolean  "certificate"
t.boolean  "free"
t.boolean  "ven"
t.integer  "capacity"
t.text     "address"
t.integer  "client_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

any ideas on how to populate a :date field ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
d1 = DateTime.new(2015, 6, 22)
```

etc. You swap months and days arguments.